# angularjs on click event not working in firefox but works fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having one strange issue with a menu implementation using Angularjs.

The below implementation works fine with Chrome but in firefox it works only sometime, and rest of the time locks all onclick event on the menu DOM object.

Here is my `menu.html` HTML template:

```
<div id="reportNav">
    <ul id="reportsMenu" ng-class="">
        <li class="tabMenu-item {{menu.classes}}" data-ng-repeat="menu in reportDetail.menusinfo">
            <label analytics-event event-source="tab_name" data-ng-bind="menu.liValue"></label>

                <ul class="submenu level1" data-ng-if="menu.subItems.length > 0"> 
                     <!-----  Sub menu implementation  --->
                </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now here is directive attached with the above html template in a `directive.js` file

```
reportDirectives.directive('reportmenudir', ['$rootScope','$timeout', '$window', function($rootScope,$timeout, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: appContext+"/menus.html",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            
            $rootScope.$on('report-loaded', function(event, args){
                if(!scope.reportViewData.reportCommand.fullReport) {
                      element.on('click', scope.handleClickEvent);
                  }
               
                scope.horizontal = scope.$eval(attrs.horizontal);

                if(scope.reportViewData.reportCommand.fullReport) {
                    $timeout(function(){
                        angular.element("li.tabMenu-item").each(function () {
                            var curObj = angular.element(this);
                            var event = {
                                target: curObj,
                                preventDefault: function () {
                                }
                            }
                            //console.log("calling", curObj.attr("id"));
                            scope.handleClickEvent(event);
                        });
                        angular.element('.floatmenu').floatmenu();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and here is definition of `handleClickEvent` function in controller.js file

```
    $scope.handleClickEvent = function (event) {
        angular.element(".tabMenu").find(".submenu").hide();
        var tarEle = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var parentEle = (tarEle) ? angular.element(tarEle).closest("li.tabMenu-item") : null;

        if (null != parentEle && !parentEle.hasClass("nodata") && !parentEle.hasClass("sel")
            && typeof (parentEle.attr("id")) != 'undefined') {
            parentEle.find(".submenu").show();
            angular.element("#reportsMenu").find(".sel").removeClass("sel");
            parentEle.addClass("sel");
            var reportObj = $scope.reportDetail;
    
            /**
             *  Get details of the selected menu and update the view etc...
             */

        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

So above implementation fails in Firefox if I open the page in new tab or open in same tab without any error message.  The strange thing is it works sometime (once in ~10 attempt).

Also the above implementation works every time in Chrome and Safari.

I have been trying to find this out since many days but there is no luck. The above JS files (after compiled as ngg-angular.js) are served using wildfly server as part of a WAR file.

In firefox debugger the onclick event is not getting caught by the above code block when menu become unresponsive, but when menu is working fine the get caught by debugger breakpoint.

[image]

What can be root cause of the this issue?

Comment: Which version of `Angular.js` you've used?

Comment: AngularJS v1.3.9

Comment: Please upload whole code somewhere to better debug

Comment: ok I am updating question description of what I found yesterday

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi : can you please tell me which file's code is required more. actually there are so many directives in the single file and all other things are working fine.

Comment: I want executable code for debug. Can you create a simple menu and attach your directive and event?

Comment: sure I will create it soon and post the link of plunker.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi : I am not able to create demo of the exact example cause  the event $rootScope.$on('report-loaded', function(event, args){ is getting broadcast after inserting so many dependencies. Let me add more information on that point in question.

Comment: When listening to events on `$rootScope` you should use the deregistration function returned by `$rootScope.$on` to remove your listener using `scope.$on('$destroy', ...)`. If you don't do this, then your listener will not be removed when the `reportmenudir` directive is destroyed.